# React Native show modal/screen only once

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

So I want to display a modal or screen only once e.g. after an update.
How do I do that? :)
I tought it would be possible to store for example a variable in another file with something like this: `shownScreen = True` but how do I do this? Or is there a build in method for this? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`react-native-async-storage`](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) to persist information about whether or not you have shown a certain screen already.

Caveat: this data will be persisted across launches of the app, but will be lost when the user uninstalls the app and installs it again. This is not a limitation of `react-native-async-storage` or React Native, though. "Vanilla" native apps suffer from it too.

Comment: So is it possible to store data like the username with react-native-async-storage also locally on the device? :D

Comment: Yes, although for sensitive data, like auth token, you might want to use something like `expo-secure-store`: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore. `react-native-async-storage` is general-purpose.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is: I use React Native CLI, is there a npm like `expo-secure-store`? :D

Comment: It is a regular npm package, you will just need to follow additional instructions for "Bare projects", outlined here: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-secure-store#installation-in-bare-react-native-projects

P.S. If I have answered your question sufficiently, please don't forget to click the checkmark near my answer.

Comment: Ah thank you! Sometimes I forgot to mark it haha